# python cannot find easy_install, how to solve this?

Tags: python, easy-install

Python 2.6 cannot find the easy_install. I have tried to install it several ways with the egg for version 2.6, but it always throws this error.

```
  Running easy_install:
/usr/bin/python "-S" "-c" "import sys,os;p = sys.path[:];import site;sys.path[:] = p;[sys.modules.pop(k) for k, v in sys.modules.items() if hasattr(v, '__path__') and len(v.__path__)==1 and not os.path.exists(os.path.join(v.__path__[0],'__init__.py'))];from setuptools.command.easy_install import main;main()" "-mUNxd" "/Applications/Plone/src/collective.xmpp.chat/eggs/tmpgMHzeC" "-q" "/tmp/tmpKqLBFPget_dist/buildout.dumppickedversions-0.5.tar.gz"
path=/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named setuptools.command.easy_install
An error occurred when trying to install buildout.dumppickedversions 0.5. Look above this message for any errors that were output by easy_install.
While:
  Installing.
  Loading extensions.
  Getting distribution for 'buildout.dumppickedversions==0.5'.
Error: Couldn't install: buildout.dumppickedversions 0.5
```

I searched extensively online but cannot find a solution. How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you have [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) installed?

Comment: Use the Macports/Homebrew Python distribution.

Comment: yes i have setup tools installed /usr/bin/easy_install-2.6 works but my ./bin/buildout -v always complains with above error. is there a way to set it to use the custom /usr/bin/easy_install-2.6 one? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that on OsX you should have an easy_install-2.6 executable in /usr/bin/ or /usr/local/bin/

Have you tried to directly use that, i.e.

/usr/bin/easy_install-2.6 install some-package

you can also try to set this environmental variable:

setenv VERSIONER_PYTHON_VERSION 2.6

or

export VERSIONER_PYTHON_VERSION=2.6

for bash

Comment: Yes this works but im running the setup tools from a /bin/buildout process and im unable to make it use this binary

Comment: setenv is not available on osx im on osx

Comment: Ok I tried but all to no avail, wiped all of my python stuff but still have issues 's quite frustrating python + plone + add-ons its just not click and go all kind of headaches, but well.. thx for the suggestion it did use the wrong python so i shall grant this as the right answer, my python install was just messed up